# Parameters passed to nested Function in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a nested function to implement algorithm like following: check the longest length of the loop in the array, values in the input array are the next index of the jump, get the max length of the loop possible, otherwise just return zero.

But if I use result instead of result[], there is error said "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment", which can not find "result" parameter in the function dfs, but visited and length could be find. After I use result instead of result, it works. Does this mean only list could be default used in nested functions ?

```
def max_length_loop(array):
    def dfs(index, len):
        if visited[index]:
            result[0] = max(result[0], len-length[index])
            return 
        visited[index] = True
        length[index] = len
        dfs(array[index], len + 1)

    if not array:
        return 0
    n = len(array)
    visited = [False for _ in xrange(n)]
    length = [0 for _ in xrange(n)]
    result = [0]
    for i in xrange(n):
        dfs(i, 0)
    return result[0] 


test = [1,2,3,4,0]
print max_length_loop(test)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do assignment inside a function, the interpreter assumes that the name on the left side is a local reference in that function, and as such defines that name as local to that particular function (this also applies to nested functions). Hence, when you are trying to access the variable `result` before actually assigning it , you get the `UnboundLocalError` .

The easiest example to show this issue -

```
>>> c = 10
>>> def a():
...     c = c + 10
...
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in a
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment
```

The same thing is happening in your case. When you change your line to `result = <something>` , you are actually doing an assignment on the `result` variable inside the function `dfs()` , which causes interpreter to treat it as a local variable , and hence as you are trying to access `result` even before it is defined, you are getting the issue.

You should not depend on such nested scopes and pass all the data you need as arguments to the function.

Also, another thing I noted is that , your logic is a bit wrong, you should reinitialize `visited` array and `length` array inside the for loop, otherwise it would return the first loop it finds as the max length loop.

Example -

```
def max_length_loop(array):
    def dfs(index, len, result, visited, length):
        if visited[index]:
            result = max(result, len-length[index])
            return result
        visited[index] = True
        length[index] = len
        return dfs(array[index], len + 1, result, visited, length)
    if not array:
        return 0
    n = len(array)
    result = 0
    for i in range(n):
        visited = [False for _ in range(n)]
        length = [0 for _ in range(n)]
        result = max(dfs(i, 0, 0, visited, length), result)
    return result

test = [1,2,3,4,0]
max_length_loop(test)
>>> 5
test = [1,2,1,4,5,6,7,3]
max_length_loop(test)
>>> 5
```

Comment: Got it ! Should be more safety to pass the parameters to the inner function. :) Maybe separate into two functions will be more clear here. Thanks for the detailed explanation !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on this line:

```
result[0] = max(result[0], len-length[index])
```

What you are wanting is to do this right?

```
result = max(result, len-length[index])
```

But then, the first time through, you are taking the maximum of result and some other value, but result hasn't been used before, so what value would be used in the max function?

You can just put this line at the top of the outer function if you want:
   result = 0

This creates a global variable named result.

And inside dfs, put

```
global result
```

So you have this (in Python 3):

```
result = 0

def max_length_loop(array):

    def dfs(index, len):
        global result
        if visited[index]:
            result = max(result, len-length[index])
            return result
        visited[index] = True
        length[index] = len
        dfs(array[index], len + 1)

    if not array:
        return 0
    n = len(array)
    visited = [False for _ in range(n)]
    length = [0 for _ in range(n)]

    for i in range(n):
        visited = [False for _ in range(n)]
        length = [0 for _ in range(n)]
        dfs(i, 0)

    return result


test = [1,2,3,4,0]
print(max_length_loop(test))
```

And what Anand said about taking the visited and length array initialisations inside the for loop is correct.